# mvn clean tomcat:run command

Tags: maven, tomcat

When I run "mvn clean tomcat:run" (without specifying any tomcat version) command from command prompt for running my web application, it download tomcat 6.0.29 version dependency as shown below:

org/apache/tomcat/juli/6.0.29/juli-6.0.29.pom

org/apache/tomcat/annotations-api/6.0.29/annotations-api-6.0.29.pom

org/apache/tomcat/catalina-ha/6.0.29/catalina-ha-6.0.29.pom

org/apache/tomcat/coyote/6.0.29/coyote-6.0.29.pom

org/apache/tomcat/tribes/6.0.29/tribes-6.0.29.pom

org/apache/tomcat/jasper-el/6.0.29/jasper-el-6.0.29.pom

org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/6.0.29/dbcp-6.0.29.pom

**pom.xml file of the application does not contain any tomcat version it require to run**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>esa</finalName>
</build>
```

So my query is how does it decide to download particular this tomcat version dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the default settings of the tomcat plugin you run.

Try running `mvn tomcat:help -Ddetails` to see what version of the plugin you use, and how it can be configured.

I think it is an earlier version of the plugin, and you can now use explicit versions, such as

```
mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.0:run
mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:run
```

(or the shorter form)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you are running the tomcat-maven-plugin from codehaus, whihc has tomcat 6.0.29 built-in. (Seems there was no activity since 2010.)
You should try the tomcat7 plugin from apache.

Regards
Tibor

Answer (score 0):

In command line for maven use `--debug` option to get explanation of build process. For our case output looks like:

`...[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix tomcat from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
...
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin to 1.1 from repository central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)...`

Actually to explain why we've got tomcat v1.1 without specifying anything about tomcat, remember that maven build process has been customized with build plugins. And each build plugins has own build plugins. So it is enough to examine effective pom file to get clear understanding that almost empty initial pom.xml has quite big effective pom.xml.

To overcome issue just use explicit version of the tomcat plugin.